# Can I play multiplayer?

Tags: crysis-2

I bought Crysis 2 Maximum Edition on the Steam Holiday Sale and downloaded it yesterday.

I speedrunned the story but now I want to play multiplayer, but with the fall of gamespy, Crysis 2 Multiplayer died too. Also the page mycrysis.com was dead for years, but now it redirects to crysis.com.

I want to know if there is a third-party way or a tweak to play online.